# VBA Before Save event - file restriction based on user entry

Tags: vba, user-interface, before-save

I have the following WB code which tries to force the user to save the file as a particular file type (.xlsm) and name (the default path & "username-gaplist" --> can be followed by ANY type after this). So far I'm almost got it working down pat, except for 1 issue with the comparison operator in the IF statement.

Option Explicit

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)

Dim txtFileName As String
Dim yn As Boolean
Dim a As String

a = Application.DefaultFilePath & "\" & Environ("UserName") & "-Gaplist.xlsm"

'1. Check of Save As was used.
   If SaveAsUI = True Then
        Cancel = True

'2. Call up your own dialog box.  Cancel out if user Cancels in the dialog box.

       txtFileName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(Environ("UserName") & "-Gaplist", "Excel Macro-Enabled Workbook (*.xlsm), *.xlsm", , "Save As XLSM file")
       'this compares the named file by user to the restriction which is username and gap list, and cancels if non-confmring

        If Left(txtFileName, Len(txtFileName)) >= Left(a, Len(txtFileName)) Then

           MsgBox Left(txtFileName, Len(txtFileName)) & vbLf & Left(a, Len(txtFileName))

            'if user hits cancel (returns value of "False")
            If txtFileName = "False" Then
            MsgBox "Action Cancelled", vbOKOnly
            Cancel = True
            Exit Sub
            End If

            'if an invalid string is entered
        Else
            MsgBox "Must be saved in following format:" & vbLf & Application.UserName & "-Gaplist" & " " & "(you can add whatever after this)", vbOKOnly, "Retry.."
            Cancel = True
            Exit Sub
        End If

'3. Save the file based on string entered

       Application.EnableEvents = False
       Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        ThisWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=txtFileName, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled
        Application.EnableEvents = True
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True

       MsgBox "Saved to: " & txtFileName, vbExclamation, Now

    End If
End Sub
```

Like I said, I know that the issue lies in the

> Left(txtFileName, Len(txtFileName)) >= Left(a, Len(txtFileName))

and the Cancel function works correctly in this setup, but I tested and this is what happens:

> Entered: username-gaplist.xlsm String(fixed): username-gaplist.xlsm
>   result: GOOD (will overwrite if already saved as display events gets
>   turned off)   Entered: usernam.xlsm String(fixed):
>   username-gaplist.xlsm result: Good (will give the user's the msgbox
>   telling them to retry as it doesn't conform)
>
> Entered: username-gaplist323423.xlsm String(fixed):
>   username-gaplist.xlsm result: Good (will save accordingly to the
>   specified file path)
>
> Entered: userzzz.xlsm String(fixed): username-gaplist.xlsm result:
>   **BAD - this is allowing the user to save** because adding the "z" means that the entered string is > than the fixed string (based on
>   same length), and it saves this . I would like to fix this
>
> Entered: (user hits cancel) String(fixed): username-gaplist.xlsm
>   result: Msgbox action cancelled - exits sub

The other thing I could try is to use a "LIKE" operator , but have little experience using this.

Anyone provide any thoughts/suggestions would be great!

THanks

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)

Dim txtFileName As String
Dim yn As Boolean
Dim a As String

a = Application.DefaultFilePath & "\" & Environ("UserName") & "-Gaplist"

'1. Check of Save As was used.
   If SaveAsUI = True Then
        Cancel = True

'2. Call up your own dialog box.  Cancel out if user Cancels in the dialog box.

       txtFileName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(Environ("UserName") & "-Gaplist", "Excel Macro-Enabled Workbook (*.xlsm), *.xlsm", , "Save As XLSM file")
       'this compares the named file by user to the restriction which is username and gap list, and cancels if non-confmring

        If txtFileName = "False" Then
             MsgBox "Action Cancelled", vbExclamation, "Cancelled.."
             Cancel = True
             Exit Sub

        ElseIf Left(WorksheetFunction.Substitute(txtFileName, ".xlsm", ""), Len(a)) = a Then
             GoTo ResumeSub

        ElseIf Left(WorksheetFunction.Substitute(txtFileName, ".xlsm", ""), Len(a)) <> a Then
             MsgBox "Must be saved in the following format: " & Chr(10) & Chr(10) & _
             Environ("username") & "-Gaplist" & "(you can enter whatever text after this)" & vbLf & vbLf & _
             "Note: Not case sensitive!", vbCritical, "Retry.."

             Cancel = True
             Exit Sub

        End If

'3. Save the file.

ResumeSub:

       Application.EnableEvents = False
       Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        ThisWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=txtFileName, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled
        Application.EnableEvents = True
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True

      MsgBox "Saved to: " & txtFileName & vbLf & vbLf & Space(15) & Date & " " & Time, vbInformation, "Saved!"

    End If
End Sub
```